# Downloading files into root app directory using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I'm new to coding for Swift and I don't have much experience of Objective C so am trying to download a file from the web (csv) and dump it into the root program directory.

Unfortunately I can't find any how-to tutorial in Swift although I am working through the tutorial at http://www.appcoda.com/background-transfer-service-ios7/ which is in ObjectiveC.

This may be really basic (and apologies) but I'm trying to create a class in Swift replacing the implementation of the FileDownloadInfo class in ObjectiveC. (If anyone has a Swift example of the tutorial, that would be REALLY helpful.

The implementation in ObjectiveC is:

```
@implementation FileDownloadInfo

-(id)initWithFileTitle:(NSString *)title andDownloadSource:(NSString *)source{
    if (self == [super init]) {
        self.fileTitle = title;
        self.downloadSource = source;
        self.downloadProgress = 0.0;
        self.isDownloading = NO;
        self.downloadComplete = NO;
        self.taskIdentifier = -1;
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

A FileDownloadArray is then populated via

```
-(void)initializeFileDownloadDataArray{
    self.arrFileDownloadData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self.arrFileDownloadData addObject:[[FileDownloadInfo alloc] initWithFileTitle:@"iOS Programming Guide" andDownloadSource:@"https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/iphoneappprogrammingguide.pdf"]];
}
```

I've created the following in a Swift class, but of course there's no function - how do I amend this to enable me to populate an array in the same way as above?

```
import UIKit

class FileDownloadInfo: NSObject {

    var fileTitle: NSString
    var downloadSource: NSString
    var downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask?
    var taskResumeData: NSData?
    var downloadProgress: Double
    var isDownloading: Bool
    var downloadComplete: Bool
    var taskIdentifier: Int

init(initWithFileTitle title: NSString, andDownloadSource source: NSString) {
        self.fileTitle = title
        self.downloadSource = source
        self.downloadProgress = 0.0
        self.isDownloading = false
        self.downloadComplete = false
        self.taskIdentifier = -1
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've only read part of the intro and this is my take on it. Hopefully, it can help. For the sake of direct translation, you can try:

```
func initializeFileDownloadDataArray(){
    arrFileDownloadData = [FileDownloadInfo]()
    arrFileDownloadData.append(FileDownloadInfo("iOS Programming Guide", downloadSource:"https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/iphoneappprogrammingguide.pdf" ))
}
```

If I read it correctly, the initializers would have a format like the one below:

```
init(title: String, downloadSource: String) {
    self.fileTitle = title
    self.downloadSource = source
    self.downloadProgress = 0.0
    self.isDownloading = false
    self.downloadComplete = false
    self.taskIdentifier = -1
}
```

Hopefully, that works.